# Is my reduction of order technique correct?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$(x−1)u′′+(x−2)u′=0$

Let $v=u'$

$(x-1)v'=-(x-2)v$

By separation of variables, I get

$\ln|v| = -x+\ln|x-1|+C$

or $v = e^{-x}+(x-1)+c_2$

Is this right so far?

Then I can get

$u' =e^{-x}+(x-1)+c_2$

Then integrate this?

And further, if I get this answer, does the solution satisfy

$(x-1)y''-xy'+y=0$ for $y>1$ if $y_1=e^x$

Comment: If $u' = e^{-x} + (x-1)+c_2$, then $(x-2)u'$ has a term $x^2$ but $(x-1)u''$ doesn't. You need to fix this.

Comment: @HansEngler I don't get what you mean.

Comment: $(x-2)u' = (x-2)e^{-x} + x^2 - 3x + 2 + c_2x - 2c_2$ but $(x-1)u'' = -(x-1)e^{-x} + (x-1)$.

Answer (score 0):

You're close, but the exponential of a sum is not the sum of exponentials.

$$\ln|v| = -x + \ln|x-1| + c_1$$ $$ \Rightarrow v = e^{-x + \ln|x-1| + c_1} = e^{-x}e^{\ln|x-1|}e^{c_1} = C(x-1)e^{-x} $$